# Using Fermat's Little Theorem to find the smallest k for which $a ^k $≡ 1(mod 11) for a = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

We know that $a^{11-1} ≡1\bmod{11}$ for all positive integers $a$ less than $11$, by *Fermat’s Little
Theorem*.

But $(11 − 1)$= $10$ is not the smallest k for which $a ^k$ ≡ 1(mod 11) for all such a.How do we find the smallest k for which $a ^k $≡ $1(mod 11)$ for a = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10.

$[$Examples: (i) $3^5$ ≡ 1(mod 11). Here k = 5 for a = 3.
(ii)$10^2$ ≡ $1(mod 11)$. Here k = 2 for a =10.$]$

How are the values of k related to $(11 − 1)= 10?$

Comment: You pose this as if it is a homework problem, as you are commanding us to "find the smallest $k\ldots$".  Can you tell us what you have done yourself on this question? For example, have you tried to answer it for $a = 1$, $2$, $3$, and $4$?

Comment: So far you have found $2$ and $5$. The relationship between these and $10$ is not difficult to guess.

Comment: $k$ is a factor of $10$.  Are you familiar with primitive roots?

Comment: No am not@J.W.Tanner

Comment: I found $\left(
\begin{array}{cccccccccc}
 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 \\
 1 & 10 & 5 & 5 & 5 & 10 & 10 & 10 & 5 & 2 \\
\end{array}
\right)$

Comment: @Raffaele but how to use fermat's little theorem here?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner What to do with primitive roots in this problem?

Comment: @user57048:  see Bernard's answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The multiplicative group $\mathbf F^\times_{11}$ is cyclic, so you can determine a generator of this group (i.e.  a primitive root of unity in $\mathbf F_{11}$. It happens that (as is often the case) $2$ is such a generator:$\DeclareMathOperator{\ord}{ord}$

\begin{array}{|r|cccccccccc|}
\hline
n=& 1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10 \\\hline
2^n& 2 & 4 & 8 & 5 & 10 & 9 & 7 & 3 & 6  & 1 \\\hline
\end{array}
For the orders of the other elements, write each of them as $2^k$ and use that the order of such an element is
$$\ord(2^k)=\frac{\ord(2)}{\gcd(k,\ord 2)}.$$

Comment: The problem is that many beginners compute non recursively the powers of all these elements, and lose time checking their calculations, whereas this way, it has to be done only for the small element $2$, and the rest is much less error-prone. Furthermore, if  you're asked the list of all primitive elements, you have them instantly: they're given  by the powers $k$ coprime to $10$.

Comment: How do I approach it if I am a beginner here. And how do I answer with Fermat's little theorem only.@Bernard.

Comment: meaning I want to know from where this table is derived from

Comment: @user57048: I computed by hand the powers of $2$ recursively (meaning that, for instance, once you  have calculated that $2^4=5$, you deduce instantly that $2^5=2\cdot5$). As to your first question, the only fact that Fermat asserts is that the order of any element is a divisor of $\varphi(11)=10$. So when you compute the powers of an element, you really have to test only $2$ and $5$.

Answer (score 1):

You are seeking the Carmichael lambda function. The Wikipedia article shows how to [compute this function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function#Computing_%CE%BB(n)_with_Carmichael%27s_theorem) using Euler's totient function and the lcm function.

EDIT: if you mean that the $a$ are independent of each other, then you are asking for a computation of multiplicative order, which is known to be a difficult problem. As far as I am aware, there is no direct formula for it.